# Simplest list wrapper for array of primitives

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm looking for ready simplest (JDK standard) list wrapper for given array of **primitives**, which **doesn't copy this array**. Say, we have `int[] arr` and desired implementation will be like just

```
List<Integer> list = new AbstractList<Integer>() {
     @Override
     public Integer get(int index) {
         return arr[index];
      }

      @Override
      public int size() {
         return arr.length;
      }
};
```

Unfortunately  `Arrays.asList(T...a)` can't do that due to its signature (it will produce `List<int[]>` in this case). Surely, I can use mentioned code above, but it seems that it's too obvious to be not already implemented.

Is anything similar (may be in java-8)?

**UPD**: This is not off-topic, because I'm looking for standard Java SE implementation, not 3d-party library!

Comment: No, there's no such thing in the JDK. But you can use an IntStream if a stream suits your needs.

Comment: @JBNizet How `IntStream` could help me?

Comment: One thing to watch out for with this is that every call to get() will necessitate boxing, which could undo the performance benefits of using int[] over Integer[].

Comment: It won't make any copy of the array, will enable you to filter, map, reduce, sort, map to objects, etc.. If you need such a kind of operations, then it can be useful. if you need random access, then just use an array, or make a copy.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion this is questionable and depends on how I will use it. But  it is nice notice

Comment: @JBNizet No, I'm only avoiding of array copy.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion if it is huge array and I have to wrap it a lot of times in some loop this could have more performance benefits

Comment: No to what? You have said what you didn't want (a copy), but you haven't said why you need such a list, why an array or a copy isn't OK, and what you would use the list for. So, except for saying "no, that doesn't exist", we can't really suggest anything concrete.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for that, I mean that I really need instance of object that implements `List` interface. I thought it is clear from my question. I can update it if it is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such thing in the JDK. You'll have to find a library that has that feature (if one exists), or to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is exhaustive answer to my question.